# How to re-write menu using DRY

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, menu

I'm doing a school project and I really feel that I can acomplish what I want in my code, however I feel like i -always- repeat my code.

I have tried to put the switch cases into methods but haven't had any success though to out of scope.

I am beginner so sorry for the eyesore code!

However, if anyone have any tips for using methods or something else so I can clean up my code a little better.

So here is a bit of my code, this is the beginning branch of my menu.

I have translated the code roughly to english.

So this is a sub menu in the main method.

```
            string[] flowers = { "Sunflower", "Coleus Tree", "Tomato" };
            int[] plant = { 0, 0, 0 };


                      switch (menuInput03)
                            {
                                /////WATER PLANT////
                                case 1:
                                    Console.Clear();
                                    Console.WriteLine("Press SPACEBAR several times to water plant!");

                                    if (plant[0] < 21)
                                    {
                                        for (int i = plant[0]; i < 21; i++)
                                        {
                                            var keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();
                                            if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
                                            {
                                                plant[0] = i;
                                                Console.Clear();
                                                Console.WriteLine("Press SPACEBAR several times to water plant!");
                                                Console.WriteLine("\nWatering plant..");
                                                Console.WriteLine("[" + flowers[0] + " " + plant[0] + "/100]");
                                            }
                                     
                                        }
                                        while (true)
                                        {
                                            Console.Clear();
                                            Console.WriteLine("Your plant has been watered!");
                                            Console.WriteLine("[" + flowers[0] + " " + plant[0] + "/100]\n");
                                            Console.WriteLine("To continue press ENTER.");
                                            var keyPressed01 = Console.ReadKey();
                                            if (keyPressed01.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                                            {
                                                Console.Clear();
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                        Console.Clear();
                                                    }
                                        }
                                    }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            Console.Clear();
                                            break;
                                case 2:
                                            Console.Clear();
                                            Console.WriteLine("Press SPACEBAR several times to remove weed!");

                                            if (plant[0] > 19)
                                            {
                                                for (int i = plant[0]; i < 51; i++)
                                                {
                                                    var keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();
                                                    if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
                                                    {
                                                        plant[0] = i;
                                                        i++;
                                                        Console.Clear();
                                                        Console.WriteLine("Press SPACEBAR several times to remove weed!");
                                                        Console.WriteLine("\nRipping out weeds..");
                                                        Console.WriteLine("[" + flowers[0] + " " + plant[0] + "/100]");
                                                    }

                                                }
                                                while (true)
                                                {
                                                    Console.Clear();
                                                    Console.WriteLine("Your plant has gotten it's weed removed!");
                                                    Console.WriteLine("[" + flowers[0] + " " + plant[0] + "/100]\n");
                                                    Console.WriteLine("To continue press ENTER.");
                                                    var keyPressed01 = Console.ReadKey();
                                                    if (keyPressed01.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                                                    {
                                                        Console.Clear();
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        Console.Clear();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            Console.Clear();
                                            break;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following; don't just copy-paste for school project without understanding what is going on. If some things are not clear do not hesitate to ask follow-up questions.

```
public record Action
{
    public string Title { get; }
    public int RequiredHealth { get; }
    public string ActionMessage { get; }
    public string CompletedMessage { get; }

    private Action(string title, int requiredHealth, string actionMessage, string completedMessage)
    {
        Title = title;
        RequiredHealth = requiredHealth;
        ActionMessage = actionMessage;
        CompletedMessage = completedMessage;
    }

    public static Action WaterPlant { get; } = new Action(
        title: "Press SPACEBAR several times to water plant!",
        requiredHealth: 20,
        actionMessage: "Watering plant..",
        completedMessage: "Your plant has been watered!");

    public static Action RemoveWeed { get; } = new Action(
        title: "Press SPACEBAR several times to remove weed!",
        requiredHealth: 50,
        actionMessage: "Ripping out weeds..",
        completedMessage: "Your plant has gotten it's weed removed!");
}

static void Main()
{
    string[] flowers = { "Sunflower", "Coleus Tree", "Tomato" };
    int[] plant = { 0, 0, 0 };

    for (var menuInput03 = 1; menuInput03 <= 2; menuInput03++)
    {
        var action = menuInput03 switch
        {
            1 => Action.WaterPlant,
            2 => Action.RemoveWeed,
        };

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine(action.Title);

        while (plant[0] < action.RequiredHealth)
        {
            if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
            {
                Console.Write("\b \b");
                continue;
            }

            plant[0]++;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(action.Title);
            Console.WriteLine(action.ActionMessage);
            Console.WriteLine($"[{flowers[0]} {plant[0]}/100]");
        }

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine(action.CompletedMessage);
        Console.WriteLine($"[{flowers[0]} {plant[0]}/100]");
        Console.WriteLine("To continue press ENTER.");

        while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            Console.Write("\b \b");
        }
        
        Console.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: So brilliant! This looks so good and will be a good template to work forward with. I will have oral examination on this so i will need to study this change of code and i'm applying for a coding school so I am interested to learn. However some questions if you would like to dummy explain. 1. public record Action //What does this mean? I am familiar with "static void Test(){Execute code}". 2. What is the meaning of { get; }? 3.Why public then private? Hope I didn't put you off with my non-knowledge.

Comment: 1. record is a special kind of type (like a class) but it behaves more like a value type. Some methods will be generated in the background by the compiler so that you do not have to write them yourself. More info on records [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records). A class would do just fine as well in this case so feel free to change it to something you already know.

Comment: 2. `{get}` makes it a read-only property. Only the Action class itself can set the value, other classes can read the values.

Comment: 3. Public so that it can be used by other classes. The constructor is private so that only the Action record itself can create instances of it and nothing else. So only known actions can be used. More info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

Comment: Alright, I will need to research further. Another question, I will still use my "                    int menuInput02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());"? Or is there already a input in your code? (Am not at scripting computer right now)

Comment: Yes you can still use your `Console.Readline()`, just remove the for loop, I added it for testing both actions.